# The expected number of random variables that should be drawn without replacement whose sum exceeds some threshold.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Say we have a finite population of $N$ points $\{x_1,\dots,x_N\}$, and we draw samples at random without replacement until their sum exceeds some threshold $t$.

We may assume that:  $\forall i\ $ $0<x_i<1$, $\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i=k$  for a known $k$, and that $0<t<k$ is known.

What is the expected number of draws?

Is there a generalization of Wald’s Equation that applies to this case?

Non-trivial bounds would be helpful too.

Comment: Are the $x_i$ distinct?

Comment: Not necessarily, but a result for distinct $x_i$ may be helpful too.

Comment: I assume you know $N$ and $k$ and $t$ and that $0 \lt t \lt k$.  If you do not know the individual $x_i$s then I think there is a distribution leading to $\frac{N}{2}$ with one $x_i$ almost $k$ and another distribution leading to $\lfloor \frac{Nt}{k}+1\rfloor$ with each $x_i = \frac{k}{N}$

Comment: I have edited my question. I forgot to mention that $x_i$s are between 0 and 1.